# Expressing 'according/as per'

Tags: grammar

> このアパートは[古]{ふる}いが、その[広]{ひろ}さ**によって**[家賃]{やちん}の[安]{やす}さが[気]{き}に[入]{い}った。

Isn't this application of `によって` valid?
'According to/based on the spaciousness of the room, the meagerness of the rent is likable'.
If not, what is the appropriate replacement?

Comment: How do you come up with the examples in your sentences?  They seem to be sentences from around the web but with misreadings and misspellings added, rendered all in kana with spaces.  Why not just copy + paste the original without mistakes?  In any case, we'd appreciate it if you'd tell us where your sentences are from when you post questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cited sentence might not be correct.
I would say the line like this:

このアパートは古いが、その広さに対する家賃の安さが気に入った。
or: このアパートは古いが、その広さに対して家賃が安いのが気に入った。
or more naturally: このアパートは古いが、広いわりに家賃が安いのが気に入った。

Note that 家賃の安さ requires an attributive form に対する "in contrast to / compared to" (so によって is wrong in this respect too), whereas 家賃が安い requires -te form に対して "in contrast to that / compared to that".

Answer (score 1):

This feels like a `～に応じて` to me -- in this case, it would be `～に応じた`.

> ～に応じて　→　in proportion to; according to; according as ([参考](http://www.excite.co.jp/dictionary/english_japanese/?search=%E5%BF%9C%E3%81%98%E3%82%8B&match=beginswith&dictionary=NEW_EJJE&block=58725&offset=66&title=%E5%BF%9C%E3%81%98%E3%82%8B))

I can't say why it feels more natural to me other than the proportionality aspect (a bigger room would obviously be more expensive).

> このアパートは古いが、その広さ**に応じた**家賃の安さが気に入った。

Answer (score 1):

> このアパートは古いが、その広さに（　　　）、家賃の安さが気に入った。
>   １）したがい　　２）よって　　　　３）加え　　　　４）関して

Choose 3. Then it will literally be like

> This apartment is old, but I liked it for its reasonable/cheap rent as well as its size/speciousness.

[Source](http://vancouverjapaneselesson.wordpress.com/2011/05/11/2011-jlpt-%E7%B7%B4%E7%BF%924-n3/)